# How to add flutter to android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have installed flutter plugin in android studio. Created new flutter project. But when the project is made there is no lib file. I have flutter sdk installed.[image: This is how it looks after project completion.]

Comment: Have you tried restarting android studio after install flutter plugin?

Comment: yes i did restart my android studio after flutter plugin installation.

Comment: Have you tried more than once? Does not seem like your project was created

Comment: yea it seems so . I tried creating another new flutter project but the result was same.